# error displaying JList in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlist

Below is the code in which I create the `JPanel`

```
public class ListBranchesInterface extends JPanel {
private Library theLibrary; // reference to back end
private ArrayList<LibraryBranch> branches;
private DefaultListModel dlm;
private JList list;
private JScrollPane scroll;

public ListBranchesInterface(Library theLibrary) {
    this.theLibrary = theLibrary;
    branches = new ArrayList<LibraryBranch>();
    branches.addAll(theLibrary.getLibraryBranches());
    System.out.println(branches.size());
    Iterator<LibraryBranch> iter = branches.iterator();
    dlm = new DefaultListModel();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {

        dlm.addElement(iter.next().toString());
        System.out.println("Added");

    }
    list = new JList(dlm); // create a JList from the default list model
    scroll = new JScrollPane(list); // add a scroll pane to the JList
    add(scroll);
    setSize(400, 400);
    setVisible(true);

}
}
```

when I add the panel to the `JFrame` nothing is displayed. (The error is not in adding it to the `JFrame` because I am adding other panels and they work properly.) What is the error?

Comment: please post an http://sscce.org/, where you displayed relations betweens JFrame and JPanels

Comment: Yes please do as @mKorbel says. I tried your code and it worked, so it is something different: setLayout, add, pack. Or toString implemented wrong.

Comment: thanks I was missing add and I didn't notice